# Get IP, MAC and hostname for all connected computers in my network

Tags: macos, networking, ip, arp

I remember doing it a few months ago, but I just forgot the command I used.
It was a one liner that produced a table output will all computers in the list: `IP   MAC   HOST`
For example:

`xx.xx.46.118   ab:cd:12:34:aa:aa       Intel Corporate (DUP: 2)`

In most sites I found `arp -a` but this output is much more limited (no hostname and it does not contain all addresses).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo arp-scan -l` in my Ubuntu machine did the job.